# php upload pdf,docx nothing happen

Tags: php

when im trying to upload pdf,docx nothing happen no errors 'n no uploads
here is my  code
please help me i dont know where is the problem i tried images and its working but pdf,doc,docx nothing happen :O

html

```
<input type="file" name="file" style="visibility:hidden;" 
                id="fileupload"  onchange="a();" /><br/>
                    <div class="input-append" >
                    <input type="file" name="filex" style="display:none;" id="fileupload"  />
                    <a class="btn btn-warning btn-large" onclick="$('#fileupload').click();">استعراض <i class="icon-white icon-print"></i> </a>
                </div>
```

php

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['cvsubmit'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $section = $_POST['section'];
    if(isset($_FILES)){
        $allowedext = array('doc','docx','pdf');
        $filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        $ext = strtolower(end(explode('.',$filename)));
        $filesize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
        $filetempname = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
        $exceptions = array();

        if(in_array($ext,$allowedext) == false){
            $exceptions[] = "<p style='color:red;font-size:18px;background:#eee;height:60px;'>صيغة الملف غير مقبولة فقط docx,doc,pdf</p>";

        if($filesize > 4096000)
        $exceptions[] = "<p style='color:red;font-size:18px;'>حجم الملف اكبر من 4 ميجا وهو الحد الاقصى</p>";

        if(empty($exceptions)){
            $dest = 'uploads/cv/'.date('d-m-y').rand(11,200000).$filename;
            if( move_uploaded_file($filetempname,$dest))
            echo "<p style='color:red;font-size:18px;'>تم الرفع بنجاح</p>";
        }
        else{
            foreach($exceptions as $excep)
            echo $excep."<br />";
        }
    }
}
}           
    ?>
```

Comment: Did you remember to set `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on the `<form>`? Also, the possible `error` in the `$_FILES` array.

Comment: yea bro its already set

Comment: Solved 
the problem was in         if(in_array($ext,$allowedext) == false){

"{" and its "}"